# form_for ActiveModel not prepopulating fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for, activemodel

I'm using form_for on an ActiveModel, Event, which has a hash :participants and a hash :emails. The keys of each hash is just a number indicating and "id" of each person and the value is their name in :participants and their email in :emails. So for example `event.emails[1]` is the email for person `event.participants[1]`. My form looks as follows:

```
= form_for @event, :url => input_constraints_path, html: {:method => :post } do |f|
  - @event.participants.keys.each do |num|
    %div
      %div.inline-block
        = f.fields_for :participants do |p|
          = p.label num
          = p.text_field num
      %div.inline-block
        = f.fields_for :emails do |e|
          = e.label "email"
          = e.email_field num
    %br
  = submit_tag "Next"
```

My ActiveModel just looks like this (using rails 3 so I couldn't use ActiveModel::Model):

```
class Event
    extend  ActiveModel::Naming
    extend  ActiveModel::Translation
    include ActiveModel::Validations
    include ActiveModel::Conversion

    attr_accessor :participants, :emails
...
end
```

For some reason when I use an existing @event ActiveModel object, it doesn't prepopulate the fields. Any suggestions?

Comment: That's a weird way to store that information and not fight a war with ActiveRecord.

Comment: What do you mean by "and not fight a war with ActiveRecord"? I agree that using an ActiveModel to store this is weird because it obviously looks like ActiveRecord should be used. But I just wanted to make a quick web app that users could use without signing up and creating accounts. The web app is 3 pages and I didn't want to store every "event" created by someone who visits the site because there isn't a way to retrieve the record without accounts to link users to events. Also the records are useless after the user is done because the last step sends out and email with the useful information.

Comment: I mean that it isn't something that works seamlessly. I think last time I had this issue, I passed the value attribute to the form helper to fill in the right value. That was for an hstore. This seems like a similar problem.

Comment: Yea that's what I ended up doing